# Partial match between two MySQL tables

Tags: mysql

> Table 1 'titles'
> ID      Title
> 1       Tommy Hilfiger men 1790790 black watch
>
> Table 2 'product'
> Supplier_name
> 1790790

I need to find the rows in table 1 where the table 2 supplier name is somewhere in the table 1 title, in this example '1790790' should be an expected result.

This query loads for ages and never completes:

```
SELECT * FROM `titles` t1
INNER JOIN product t2 ON t2.supplier_name LIKE CONCAT('%', t1.title, '%');
```

Where did I go wrong with this query?

Comment: @lelio faieta 
why did you edit the sample data, it is not understandable now?

Comment: Have you tried omitting the `INNER` and just use `JOIN`... If it helps care to find out the difference between `INNER JOIN` and `JOIN`

Comment: I think a `LEFT JOIN` is what you want here

Answer (score 0):

I think a `LEFT JOIN` is what you want here

```
SELECT * FROM `titles` t1
LEFT JOIN product t2 ON t2.supplier_name LIKE CONCAT('%', t1.title, '%');
```

Comment: it finds only word matches 'hilfiger' this way, not the product code i am looking. the above sample data is not coming up, althoigh it should.

Comment: this one returns 0 results:

SELECT * from product t2
WHERE supplier_name IN(SELECT CONCAT('%', t1.title, '%') FROM `titles` t1)

Comment: You would need to combine LIKE and IN to make that last one work

Comment: Thank you. I am a bit stuck with it now. Would you help me combining them?

Comment: I don't think you can combine LIKE and IN